# How to add Electron's printing option in an Angular 2 component?

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

I am using Angular 2 with Electron. Here I added printing option in Electron's menu, but actually I want that not to add print option in Electron's menu. I want to add it in each page of HTML templates.

```
import { app, BrowserWindow, screen, Menu, webContents,} from 'electron';
import * as path from 'path';

let win, serve;
let contents = webContents;

const args = process.argv.slice(1);
serve = args.some(val => val === '--serve');

if (serve) {
  require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
  });
}
const template = [
  // {
  //   label: 'Edit',

  //   submenu: [
  //     {role: 'undo'},
  //     {role: 'redo'},
  //     {role: 'cut'},
  //     {role: 'copy'},
  //     {role: 'paste'},
  //     {role: 'pasteandmatchstyle'},
  //     {role: 'delete'},
  //     {role: 'selectall'}
  //   ]
  // },
  {
    label: 'View',
    submenu: [
      {role: 'reload'},
      {role: 'forcereload'},
      {role: 'toggledevtools'},
      {role: 'resetzoom'},
      {role: 'zoomin'},
      {role: 'zoomout'},
      {role: 'togglefullscreen'}
    ]
  },
  // {
  //   role: 'window',
  //   submenu: [
  //     {role: 'minimize'},
  //     {role: 'close'}
  //   ]
  // },
  // {
  //   role: 'help',
  //   submenu: [ ]
  // },
      {
        ***

label: 'Print',
        click () { win.webContents.print({silent: false, printBackground: false, deviceName: ''})}

***
      },

  //   {
  //     label:'Drugs',
  //     submenu: [
  //     {
  //       label: 'Resus Drugs',
  //       click () {win.webContents.canGoForward()}
  //     },
  //      {
  //       label: 'Intubation',
  //       click () { }
  //     },
  //      {
  //       label: 'Arrythmias',
  //       click () { }
  //     },
  //      {
  //       label: 'Infusion',
  //       click () { }
  //     },
  //      {
  //       label: 'Fluids',
  //       click () { }
  //     },

  //   ]
  // },
]


const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);


function createWindow() {

  const electronScreen = screen;
  const size = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize;

  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    // frame:false,
    backgroundColor: '#97b714',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: size.width,
    height: size.height
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
  // Open the DevTools.
  // if (serve) {
  //   win.webContents.openDevTools();
  // }

  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  win.on('closed', () => {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store window
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    win = null;
  });
}

try {

  // This method will be called when Electron has finished
  // initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
  // Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
  app.on('ready', createWindow);

  // Quit when all windows are closed.
  app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
      app.quit();
    }
  });

  app.on('activate', () => {
    // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (win === null) {
      createWindow();
    }
  });

} catch (e) {
  // Catch Error
  // throw e;
}
```